# JavaScript/Typescript - Is it possible to measure how long a variable's value has been set?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using Typescript with a Javascript library for making a traffic simulator. Now, I would like to know how long a traffic light has been red for. In my code, the traffic light would be changed to green if a certain boolean value for controlling the color of the light variable is true. I am thinking if I am able to measure how long this boolean variable has been set for true. So that I could return the time duration of the traffic light. My code is too long to post all of them on it. But there's some code that associated with setting traffic light:

1. If I want to set a traffic light to green, this function would be called:

   ```
   setDirAtInter(dir: TLDir, loc: number){
     //North-South
     if(dir == 0){
       this.intersections_arr[loc].NS = true;
     }
     //East-West
     else if(dir == 1){
       this.intersections_arr[loc].EW = true;        
     }
   }
   ```

   The intersection_arr is an array containing instances of `intersection` class
2. Then the boolean variable has been set, and the codes below which is inside of the `intersection` class would be affected for setting the traffic light color:

   ```
    if(this.NS == true){
      this.right = "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)";
      this.left = "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)";
      this.top = "rgba(0,255,0,0.4)";
      this.bottom = "rgba(0,255,0,0.4)";
    }
   ```
3. Then the code below inside the `intersection` class would be affected to draw the traffic light:

   ```
   this.ctx.save();
   if(this.top == "rgba(0,255,0,0.4)"){
      //green
      var shadow_color = 'rgba(0,255,0,1)';
   }
   else{
      var shadow_color = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';
   }

   //console.log();
   this.ctx.fillStyle = shadow_color;
   this.ctx.shadowColor = shadow_color
   this.ctx.shadowOffsetY = -2;
   this.ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
   /**
     * Right Traffic Light at Top side
   */
     this.ctx.fillRect(this.x+4,this.y-2,6,6);
     this.ctx.fill();
     this.ctx.restore();
     this.ctx.shadowOffsetX = undefined;
     this.ctx.shadowBlur = undefined;
   ```

   The `ctx` is the `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. Is there anyway that I can measure how long the traffic light has been set for green?

Comment: I don't know Typescript, but...just set a variable `timeChanged = new Date()` to store the current time whenever the colour changes. Then `new Date() - timeChanged` will tell you how many milliseconds since the last time it changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do so I suppose. Use a `setInterval` and keep checking the value of the variable till it changes.

```
let value = true;
let time = 0;
let previousValue = value;
const resolution = 1000; // 1 second
const handle = setInterval(() => {
  previousValue === value ? time += resolution : clearInterval(handle);
}, resolution);
```

The value of `time` will be in milliseconds. That is *approximately* the time duration when it got first modified.

Comment: Thanks! what if I am not tracking the first time the value got modified but instead tracking how long the variable has been set for a certain value?

Comment: Certain value, or the latest value? if you want to check for the latest value and query it at any point within your application, then you will have to implement the above as a function.
If you want to do it for any arbitrary value, then do the same as above and create an array of histories (time series).

Comment: Let me see if I can create a codepen or fiddle for this. Regardless you will have to wrap all your values inside an object so they can be passed by reference.

Comment: Thanks! For example, how long has the `value = true` has been set?